# How to properly process custom commands via strings?

Tags: c#, command

To keep it short: I am making a server program for a game that I am developping.
To control the server I want to make use of commands. Something like "/Server Start 5555".
These commands are send to the server in string format. This is my code:

```
ServerCommandsClass ServerCommands = new ServerCommandsClass();
Type Service = typeof(ServerCommandsClass);
MethodInfo method = Service.GetMethod(Signals[Count].MessageArray[0]);

List<object> ObjectList = new List<object>();
for (int i = 1; i < Signals[Count].MessageArray.Length; i++)
{
    ObjectList.Add(Signals[Count].MessageArray[i]);
}

string result = Convert.ToString(method.Invoke(ServerCommands, ObjectList.ToArray()));
```

It looks messy, because it is...

Basically what I got is a class (SignalClass) which stores new messages/commands. First I determine if a message is a command. If so, this code is ran. My MessageArray contains the message word by word using the string.split function.

This works, but I feel this is a bit of a work-around.

What I want is a command infrastructure (somewhat like in minecraft) which is easy to adjust to my needs. Like in minecraft you can type: "/tp 1000 64 1000" and "/tp someplayer 1000 64 1000". In mine you can't due to the limitations of my code. I would have to make a new method "tp2" or something to be able to take that extra parameter.

I hope someone can help me with this problem, because it's very annoying.

b.t.w. I used .Net 4.5.1 to programm this. And if I'm a little vague somewhere, just ask me and I will clarify.

Dion Dokter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, the problem is not in the code that you posted, but in the methods that you are invoking.
What you're trying to do is basically overloading.

```
/tp x y z
```

and

```
/tp someplaya x y z
```

Are no different than String.Substring(0) and String.Substring(0, 5). If you catch my drift.

So, I imagine your methods look something like this:

```
public static void Teleport(params object[])
{
   //here you validate your parameters and take decisions
   //e.g.
   //if(params[0] is String && params[1] is Int32)...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, agreed that String.Split is a bit bothersome if your split character makes it into a command, so I say use an XML structure;

```
<Command>
<CommandName value="">
<Arg1 value="">
<Arg2 value="">etc...
</Command>
```

Also, depending on the game (multiplayer connecting to the same server?) use multiple ports, and you can use multiple ports for different functions in the game even for the same client (if the game is complicated enough to warrant that). That would help you segregate your command logic.

But ultimately, you are stuck with parsing what command is incoming, for debug stages of you game stick with meaningful string names, before deployment you can cut these down to same a few bytes.

And as for determining the users text-entry-as-command, a command like you have `/tp`, then String.Split, recommend forcing the first parameters to be the required parameters, then the optional parameters. And on a personal note, a command typed, should then show a list of parameters, that the user then 'types-over' to help them

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be: Don't use strings.

If you have to you could use serialization. So you can send any object. Also if your problem is about you want to be able to send different number of parameters (its a bit hard to guess what you are up to, here) use the params-keyword

like in

```
public void DoSomething (string command, params string[] paramters) {
// Whatever
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers! But if I were not to use strings, how would it be possible to do then?

Answer (score 0):

I tell you a way that we did this in-house.
We made a js proc called RemoteInvoke.  It would take a command and an array of arguments and ship them off to the server.  The server would then take the command and look for a method via reflection that was:

1. Named for the command
2. Had the `[RemoteInvocable]` attribute
3. Was public
4. Had the right number of arguments which would be type matched in.

The reason being that when I wanted to call something, I'd call RemoteInvoke which would ship off the arguments to the server.  To add a new command, I could just do this:

```
[RemoteInvocable]
public void Tp(double x, double y, double z)
{
    Tp("default", x, y, z);
}

[RemoteInvocable]
public void Tp(string location, double x, double y, double z)
{
   // whatever
}
```

The point being that the command processing was tricky, but the same for everything - just a bunch of reflection and type inference, but once done adding a new command or multiple commands with the same name and different arguments was trivial.